# How to set background from image file in pygtk+ 3

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

How to set background from image file in pygtk+ 3 ?
I tried with this but all the rest items in the application goes above it or below the image. I can change the bg colour with Gdk, but I want to see my custom made image in the background of the application.

```
image = Gtk.Image()
image.set_from_file("image.png")
self.add(image)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three possibilities:

- use CSS to specify the background image for your application window
- use a `Gtk.Overlay` and put your image widget under the other widgets in the window
- implement a custom `do_draw` function and render the background using Cairo before chaining up to the parent's implementation of `do_draw`